# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x) \sin(y) \sin(x+y)}{x y(x+y)} ~{\rm d}x ~{\rm d}y$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, multiple-integral

I came across the problem of evaluating the double integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x) \sin(y) \sin(x+y)}{x y(x+y)} ~{\rm d}x ~{\rm d}y$$
My attempt at this was to substitute $\sin(x) \cos(y) + \cos(x) \sin(y)$ for $\sin(x+y)$, although I had no clue where to go from there. My second attempt was to use trigonometric identities to rewrite the integral as:
$$\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2x) + \sin(2y) - \sin(2x + 2y)}{x^2 y + x y^2} ~{\rm d}x ~{\rm d}y$$
Which didn't seem to help, so I continued to get:
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2x) \sin^2 (y) + \sin(2y) \sin^2 (x)}{x^2 y + x y^2} ~{\rm d}x ~{\rm d}y$$
I am sure I am missing something, but I am unsure how to integrate this. Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: [$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x) \sin(y) \sin(x+y)}{x y(x+y)} ~{\rm d}x ~{\rm d}y=\frac{\pi^2}6$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4096341/686284)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This integral appeared as problem 11953 in the American Mathematical Monthly, Vol.124, January 2017 (proposed C. I. Valean (Romania)). The result is $\zeta(2)$.

This is the solution that 
I submitted a few months. For more solutions you can take a look at this [page](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~tauraso/AMM/amm.html).

We have that
$$\frac{|\sin(x) \sin(y) \sin(x+y)|}{xy(x+y)}\leq 
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
        \frac{1}{xy(x+y)}  
        & \text{for $(x,y)\in [1,+\infty)\times [1,+\infty)$}\\
        \frac{1}{x(x+y)}  
        & \text{for $(x,y)\in [1,+\infty)\times [0,1]$}\\
        \frac{1}{y(x+y)}  
        & \text{for $(x,y)\in [0,1]\times [1,+\infty)$}\\
        1  
        & \text{for $(x,y)\in [0,1]\times [0,1]$}\\
        \end{array}\right. 
$$
Moreover
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{xy(x+y)}\right)dy=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(y+1)}{y^2}dy=2\ln(2),$$
and
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x(x+y)}\right)dy=
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(y+1)}{y}dy=
\frac{\pi^2}{12}.$$
Therefore, by Fubini-Tonelli Theorem, the given double integral can be written as iterated integrals
\begin{align*}
I&:=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x) \sin(y) \sin(x+y)}{xy(x+y)}\,dx\,dy=\lim_{R\to +\infty} 
\int_{x=0}^{R}\left(\int_{y=0}^{R}\frac{\sin(x) \sin(y) \sin(x+y)}{xy(x+y)}\,dx\right)\,dy\\
&=\lim_{R\to +\infty} 2\int_{x=0}^{R}\left(\int_{y=0}^{x}\frac{\sin(x) \sin(y) \sin(x+y)}{xy(x+y)}\,dy\right)\,dx\\
&=\lim_{R\to +\infty}\frac{1}{2}\int_{x=0}^{R}\left(\int_{y=0}^{x}\frac{\sin(2x)+\sin(2y)-\sin(2x+2y)}{xy(x+y)}\,dy\right)\,dx.
\end{align*}
Then, after letting $u=2x$, $v=2y=tu$,
\begin{align*}
I&=\lim_{R\to +\infty}\int_{u=0}^{R}\left(\int_{v=0}^{u}\frac{\sin(u)+\sin(v)-
\sin(u+v)}{uv(u+v)}\,dv\right)\,du\\
&=\lim_{R\to +\infty}\int_{u=0}^{R}\left(\int_{t=0}^{1}\frac{\sin(u)+\sin(tu)-
\sin(u+tu)}{t(1+t)u^2}\,dt\right)\,du
=\lim_{R\to +\infty}\int_{t=0}^{1}\frac{f_R(t)}{t(1+t)}\,dt,
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
f_R(t):=\int_{u=0}^{R}&\frac{\sin(u)+\sin(tu)-\sin(u+tu)}{u^2}\,du
=\left[-\frac{\sin(u)+\sin(tu)-\sin(u+tu)}{u}\right]_{u=0}^{R}\\
&\qquad+\int_{u=0}^{R}\frac{\cos(u)-\cos((1+t)u)}{u}\,du
+t\int_{u=0}^{R}\frac{\cos(tu)-\cos((1+t)u)}{u}\,du.
\end{align*}
By using the Frullani's integral,
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(au)-\cos(bu)}{u}\,dt=\ln(b/a)
\qquad\mbox{for $a,b>0$,}$$
it follows that
$$\lim_{R\to +\infty} f_R(t)=f(t):=\ln(1+t)+t\ln((1+t)/t)=(1+t)\ln(1+t)-t\ln(t).$$
Note that for any $t\in [0,1]$,
$$|f_R(t)-f(t)|\leq \int_{R}^{\infty}\frac{3}{u^2}\,du=\frac{3}{R}.$$
Hence, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem, we finally obtain
\begin{align*}
I&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(t)}{t(1+t)}\,dt
=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}dt-\left[\ln(t)\ln(1+t)\right]_0^1+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}dt\\
&=2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}dt=
2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\int_0^1 t^{n-1}dt
=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}=\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Your maths are very good. In the past I tried to use changes of variables in the integral $\frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}z\sin(z)I(z)dz$ (now I believe that there is a typo in the formula by user75829) from this comment of a [post in MathOverflow.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/197917/interesting-integral#comment709222_197917) I don't know if there are (in the literature) attempts of interesting changes of variable when one evokes the calculation of $\zeta(3)$ in closed-form. I add this comment if you want to explore it in your home. Thus isn't required a response of this message, good week.

Comment: (+1) Nicely done. And *Hi* to Cornel.

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x}\sin\pars{y}\sin\pars{x + y}
\over xy\pars{x + y}}\,\dd x\,\dd y}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x}\sin\pars{y}\over xy}\
\overbrace{\bracks{{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic k\pars{x + y}}\dd k}}
^{\ds{\sin\pars{x + y} \over x + y}}\ \,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\bracks{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}
\,\expo{\ic k x}\,\dd x}^{2}\dd k\label{1}\tag{1}
=
{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}
\bracks{\pi + 2\ic\,\mrm{arctanh}\pars{k} \over 2}^{2}\dd k
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}
\bracks{\pi^{2} - 4\,\mrm{arctanh}^{2}\pars{k}}\dd k
=
{\pi^{2} \over 4} -
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - k \over 1 + k}\,\dd k
\\[5mm] \stackrel{t\ =\ \pars{1 - k}/\pars{1 + k}}{=}\,\,\,&
{\pi^{2} \over 4} - {1 \over 2}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{t} \over \pars{1 + t}^{2}}\,\dd t}
_{\ds{\pi^{2} \over 6}}
=
{\pi^{2} \over 4} - {1 \over 2}\,{\pi^{2} \over 6} =
 \bbx{\pi^{2} \over 6}\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

In this answer, there are some gaps to be filled in by the reader (such as why the integration operators commute and why they commute with taking a limit).  This answer is similar to Felix Marin's solution.

Write $$\text{sinc}(q)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{\sin(q)}{q}&\text{if }q\neq 0\,,\\
1&\text{if }q=0\,.
\end{array}
\right.$$  Observe that
$$\text{sinc}(q)=\frac{1}{2}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\exp(\text{i}pq)\,\text{d}p\,.$$
Hence, the integral $\displaystyle I:=\int_0^\infty\,\int_0^\infty\,\text{sinc}(x)\,\text{sinc}(y)\,\text{sinc}(x+y)\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y$ can be written as
$$\begin{align} I&=\frac{1}{8}\,\int_0^\infty\,\int_0^\infty\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\exp(\text{i}rx)\,\exp(\text{i}sy)\,\exp\big(\text{i}t(x+y)\big)\,\text{d}r\,\text{d}s\,\text{d}t\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y
\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\,\small\frac{1}{8}\,\int_0^\infty\,\int_0^\infty\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\exp(\text{i}rx)\,\exp(\text{i}sy)\,\exp\big(\text{i}(t+\text{i}\epsilon)(x+y)\big)\,\text{d}r\,\text{d}s\,\text{d}t\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y
\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\,\small\frac{1}{8}\,\int_0^\infty\,\int_0^\infty\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\exp\big(\text{i}(r+t+\text{i}\epsilon)x\big)\,\exp\big(\text{i}(s+t+\text{i}\epsilon)y\big)\,\text{d}r\,\text{d}s\,\text{d}t\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,.
\end{align}$$
Ergo,
$$
\begin{align}
I&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\,\small\frac18\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_0^\infty\,\int_0^\infty\,\exp\big(\text{i}(r+t+\text{i}\epsilon)x\big)\,\exp(\text{i}(s+t+\text{i}\epsilon)y\big)\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}r\,\text{d}s\,\text{d}t
\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\,\frac18\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\left(\frac{\text{i}}{r+t+\text{i}\epsilon}\right)\,\left(\frac{\text{i}}{s+t+\text{i}\epsilon}\right)\,\text{d}r\,\text{d}s\,\text{d}t
\\
&=-\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\,\frac18\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\Biggl(\ln\left(\frac{t+\text{i}\epsilon+1}{t+\text{i}\epsilon-1}\right)\Biggr)^2\,\text{d}t\\
&=-\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\,\frac18\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\Biggl(\ln\left(\frac{1+t+\text{i}\epsilon}{1-t-\text{i}\epsilon}\right)+\text{i}\pi\Biggr)^2\,\text{d}t
\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\,\frac18\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\Biggl(\pi^2-2\pi\text{i}\,\ln\left(\frac{1+t+\text{i}\epsilon}{1-t-\text{i}\epsilon}\right)-\Bigg(\ln\left(\frac{1+t+\text{i}\epsilon}{1-t-\text{i}\epsilon}\right)\Bigg)^2\Biggr)\,\text{d}t
\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{4}-\frac18\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\Bigg(\ln\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)\Bigg)^2\,\text{d}t\,,
\end{align}$$
noting that
$$\small\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\ln\left(\frac{1+t+\text{i}\epsilon}{1-t-\text{i}\epsilon}\right)\,\text{d}t=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\,\Biggl((2+\text{i}\epsilon)\,\ln(2+\text{i}\epsilon)-(2-\text{i}\epsilon)\,\ln(2-\text{i}\epsilon)+2\pi\epsilon-2\text{i}\epsilon\,\ln(\epsilon)\Biggr)=0\,.$$
Now, by setting $u:=\frac{1}{2}\,\ln\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)$, we see that $t=\tanh(u)$, so
$$\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\Bigg(\ln\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)\Bigg)^2\,\text{d}t=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\frac{(2u)^2}{\big(\cosh(u)\big)^2}\,\text{d}u=4\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\left(\frac{u}{\cosh(u)}\right)^2\,\text{d}u\,.$$

We now need to show that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\,\left(\frac{u}{\cosh(u)}\right)^2\,\text{d}u=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\,.$$
Use the closed contour  $$\gamma_L:=[-L,+L]\cup[+L,+L+2\pi\text{i}]\cup[+L+2\pi\text{i},-L+2\pi\text{i}]\cup[-L+2\pi\text{i},-L]\,,$$
oriented in the counterclockwise direction, to evaluate the integral
$$\lim_{L\to\infty}\,\oint_{\gamma_L}\,\frac{u^3}{\big(\cosh(u)\big)^2}\,\text{d}u=-6\pi\text{i}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\left(\frac{u}{\cosh(u)}\right)^2\,\text{d}u+8\pi^3\text{i}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\frac{\text{d}u}{\big(\cosh(u)\big)^2}\,.$$
Since 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\frac{\text{d}u}{\big(\cosh(u)\big)^2}=\big(\tanh(u)\big)\Big|^{u=+\infty}_{u=-\infty}=2\,,$$
we conclude that
$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\left(\frac{u}{\cosh(u)}\right)^2\,\text{d}u
&=\frac{16\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{6\pi\text{i}}\,\left(\lim_{L\to\infty}\,\oint_{\gamma_L}\,\frac{u^3}{\big(\cosh(u)\big)^2}\,\text{d}u\right)
\\&=\small\frac{16\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{3}\,\text{Res}_{u=\frac{\pi\text{i}}{2}}\left(\frac{u^3}{\big(\cosh(u)\big)^2}\right)-\frac{1}{3}\,\text{Res}_{u=\frac{3\pi\text{i}}{2}}\left(\frac{u^3}{\big(\cosh(u)\big)^2}\right)\,.
\end{align}$$
Note that
$$\text{Res}_{u=\frac{\pi\text{i}}{2}}\left(\frac{u^3}{\big(\cosh(u)\big)^2}\right)=\frac{3\pi^2}{4}\text{ and }\text{Res}_{u=\frac{3\pi\text{i}}{2}}\left(\frac{u^3}{\big(\cosh(u)\big)^2}\right)=\frac{27\pi^2}{4}\,.$$
That is,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\left(\frac{u}{\cosh(u)}\right)^2\,\text{d}u=\frac{16\pi^2}{6}-\frac{3\pi^2}{12}-\frac{27\pi^2}{12}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\,.$$
Consequently,
$$I=\frac{\pi^2}{4}-\frac{1}{8}\Biggl(4\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)\Biggr)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\zeta(2)\,,$$
where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta-function.

---

Interestingly, we have $$J:=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\text{sinc}(x)\,\text{sinc}(y)\,\text{sinc}(x+y)\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y=\pi^2\,.$$
To show this, we proceed as before:
$$\begin{align} J&=\frac{1}{8}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\exp(\text{i}rx)\,\exp(\text{i}sy)\,\exp\big(\text{i}t(x+y)\big)\,\text{d}r\,\text{d}s\,\text{d}t\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y
\\&=\frac{1}{8}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\exp\big(\text{i}(r+t)x\big)\,\exp(\text{i}(s+t)y\big)\,\text{d}r\,\text{d}s\,\text{d}t\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y
\\&=\frac{1}{8}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\exp\big(\text{i}(r+t)x\big)\,\exp\big(\text{i}(s+t)y\big)\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}r\,\text{d}s\,\text{d}t\,.
\end{align}$$
Let $\delta$ denote the Dirac delta distribution (noting that $\displaystyle\delta(p)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\exp(\text{i}pq)\,\text{d}q$).  This gives
$$\begin{align}
J&=\frac{1}{8}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\big(2\pi\,\delta(r+t)\big)\,\big(2\pi\,\delta(s+t)\big)\text{d}r\,\text{d}s\,\text{d}t\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{2}\,\int_{-1}^{+1}\,\text{d}t=\pi^2=6\,\zeta(2)\,.
\end{align}$$
As a consequence,
$$\int_0^\infty\,\int_0^\infty\,\text{sinc}(x)\,\text{sinc}(y)\,\text{sinc}(x-y)\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y=\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\frac{\pi^2}{3}=2\,\zeta(2)\,.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$I=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)\ln(x+y)}{xy(x+y)}\ dx\ dy$$

and

$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)\cos(y)\sin(a(x+y))}{xy(x+y)}\ dx\ dy,\quad I(0)=0,\quad I(1)=I$$

$$I'(a)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)\cos(y)\cos(a(x+y))}{xy}\ dx\ dy$$
$$=\Re\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)\cos(y)e^{ia(x+y)}}{xy}\ dx\ dy$$

$$=\Re\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)e^{iax}}{x}\cdot\frac{\sin(y)e^{iay}}{y}\ dx\ dy=\Re\left(\color{blue}{\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)e^{iax}}{x}\ dx}\right)^2$$
$$=\Re\left(i\ \text{arctanh}(1/a)\right)^2=-\Re\ \text{arctanh}^2{(1/a)}$$

$$\Longrightarrow I=-\Re\int_0^1\text{arctanh}(1/a)^2\ da=-\frac14\Re\int_0^1\ln^2\left(-\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right)\ da=-\frac12\Re\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(-x)}{(1+x)^2}\ dx$$

$$=-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(x)-\pi^2}{(1+x)^2}\ dx=-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(x)}{(1+x)^2}\ dx+\frac{\pi^2}2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\ dx}_{1/2}$$
$$=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nn\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln^2(x)\ dx+\frac{\pi^2}{4}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}+\frac{\pi^2}{4}=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{\pi^2}{4}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

---

Proving the blue integral;

Let $$A=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)e^{iax}}{x}\ dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)e^{-\frac{a}{i}x}}{x}\ dx$$

and $$I(r)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(r x)e^{-\frac{a}{i}x}}{x}\ dx, \quad I(0)=0, \quad I(1)=A$$

$$\Longrightarrow I'(r)=\int_0^\infty \cos(r x)e^{-\frac{a}{i}x}\ dx=\frac{a/i}{r^2+(a/i)^2}=-\frac{ia}{r^2-a^2}$$

$$\Longrightarrow A=i\int_0^1\frac{a}{a^2-r^2}\ dr=i\ \text{arccoth}(a)=i\ \text{arctanh}(1/a)$$

Comment: Essentially it is the same derivation as  [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2749320), is not it?

Comment: @user this problem was posted in this group 
 . https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2827873713999764&set=gm.676922559737581&type=3&theater&ifg=1  and i posted my solution there yesterday, but when Cornel shared the MSE link there, i posted my solution here . I  hope this clears your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Write the integral as
$$
I = \mathrm{Im} \int_0^\infty dx \int_0^\infty dy \frac{\sin x \sin y}{xy(x+y)}e^{i(x+y)}
$$
Define
$$
J(a) \equiv \int_0^\infty dx \int_0^\infty dy \frac{\sin x \sin y}{xy(x+y)}e^{ia(x+y)}
$$
so
$$
J'(a) = i \int_0^\infty dx \int_0^\infty dy \frac{\sin x \sin y}{xy}e^{ia(x+y)} \equiv i (K(a))^2,
$$
where
$$
K(a) = \int_0^\infty dx \frac{\sin x}{x}e^{i a x}
$$
We have, for $\mathrm{Im}\ a = \epsilon > 0$,
$$
K'(a) = i\ \int_0^\infty dx \sin x\ e^{i a x} = \frac i 2 \left[\frac{1}{a+1} - \frac{1}{a-1} \right]
$$
so
$$
K(a) = \int_{\infty + \epsilon i}^{a} dz\ K'(z) = i\ \mathrm{arctanh}(1/a)
$$

We have, for example from Riemann-Lebesgue,
$$
J(\infty+\epsilon i) = 0
$$
whence
$$
J(1) = \int_\infty^1 da\ J'(a)
$$
Taking the imaginary part, we get
$$
I = \int_1^\infty dx\ \mathrm{arctanh}^2 \frac 1 x = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2}\ \mathrm{arctanh}^2 x \\= \frac 1 4 \int_0^1 dx\ \frac{\ln^2(1+x)+\ln^2(1-x)-2 \ln(1+x)\ln(1-x)}{x^2}
$$
The integral can be evaluated by finding the antiderivative expressed in terms of the polylogarithm, or by a series expansion. I don't have time to write down all the steps, which are standard. The result is
$$
I = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$