# How to find integral $\int_0^\infty\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x \sin y \sin (x+y)}{xy(x+y)}\,dx\,dy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Find the integral
$$I=\int_0^\infty\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x \sin y \sin (x+y)}{xy(x+y)}\,dx\,dy$$

My try: define
$$I(b):=\int_0^\infty\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x \sin y \sin (x+y)}{xy(x+y)}e^{-bxy(x+y)}\,dx\,dy$$
then
$$I'(b)=-\int_0^\infty\int_0^{\infty}\sin x \sin y \sin (x+y) e^{-bxy(x+y)}\,dx\,dy$$

But I can't find $I(b)$.

Thank you

Comment: I have answered a [more general](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3778528) question a while back.

Comment: A very nice general solution from @metamorphy. It is surprisingly concise: $I(n)=\pi^nB_n$, where $B_n$ is Bernoulli number. For $n=2$ it gives immediately $\pi^2/6$. I saw several such problems solved (for given $n=1,2,3$) and even evaluated one of them (for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513089/unexpected-appearances-of-pi2-6?noredirect=1 or https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2465658p20815855) , but could never have imagined that there were such solution for the general case. The beauty of mathematics is infinite :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $I=J(1)$, where

$$J(a) =\int_0^\infty\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x \sin y \sin [a(x+y)]}{xy(x+y)} dx dy$$
and
\begin{align}
J’(a) &=\int_0^\infty\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x \sin y \cos [a(x+y)]}{xy} dx dy\\
& =\int_0^\infty\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x \sin y [\cos (ax)\cos(ay)- \sin (ax)\sin(ay)]}{xy} dx dy\\
 & =\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x \cos (ax)}xdx \right)^2
- \left(\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x \sin (ax)}xdx \right)^2\\
& =\frac14\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin (1-a)x + \sin (1+a)x }{x}  dx\right)^2\\
& \>\>\>\>\>\>\>-\frac14\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos (1-a)x -\cos (1+a)x }{x} dx\right)^2\\
&=\frac14\left(\pi^2 - \ln^2 \frac{1+a}{1-a} \right)
\end{align}
Thus
$$I=\int_0^1 J’(a)da=\frac14 \int_0^1 \left(\pi^2 - \ln^2 \frac{1+a}{1-a} \right) da=\frac14 \left(\pi^2 - \frac{\pi^2}3 \right) 
=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$

Comment: This is a nice answer !

Comment: May I ask how did you get the $\pi^2/3$?

Comment: @athos - integrate $$\int_0^1 \ln^2 \frac{1+a}{1-a} da \overset{\frac{1-a}{1+a}\to a}=\int_0^1 \frac{2\ln^2 a}{(1+a)^2}da
\overset{IBP}= -\int_0^1 \frac{4\ln a}{1+a}da
=\frac{\pi^2}{3}
$$

Comment: @Quanto just found the last step can also be derived via [one of your other answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3826136/26632), thank you, I learnt another trick.